# Cookie not accessible through client after set-cookie response from server

Tags: java, angular, spring, cookies, spring-cloud-gateway

I use Spring Cloud Gateway as authentication and authorization which sits before the API server.

After the client authorized we put `set-cookie` with the JWT as the response header, i.e., `Set-Cookie: my-token=jwtXXX`

When the client receives the response, he does not have access to the cookie through `document.cookie`

- We used `ResponseCookie` class of spring and created a cookie with `path=/` and `httpOnly=false`.
- We added `Set-Cookie` to `Access-Control-Expose-Header`

```java
ResponseCookie jwtCookie = ResponseCookie.from('my-token', 'jwtXXX')
    .httpOnly(false)
    .path("/")
    .build()

exchange.getResponse()
        .addCookie(jwtCookie)

return chain.filter(exchange)
```

If we look at the logs we see the following response:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> // Headers..
> set-cookie: my-token=jwtXXX; Path=/
> ```

The cookie is received as `ResponseCookie` on dev tools network tab and is sent to the server with each request on the cookie.

But after the response, if I print the cookies using

```js
~> document.cookie
<~ ""
```

No cookie is present on the document.

We want to access to the token as he holds the auth data, which determines the UI layout.